# How to check and change the value of a list?

Tags: list, vim, compare

I would like to check all list values in a list and change them if necessary.

p.e.

I want to check the next lists if there are values higher or lower then the next values:
`min-value = 6`
`max-value = 22`

`mylist = ['4-8','25','16-19','21-32']`

if one of the list values is below the min-value or higher then the max-value, the list values must be changed to the min-value and max-value. p.e. in example, the new list must be:

`mylist = ['6-8','22','16-19','21-22']`

if the entire value of the list item is below the min-value or higher then the max-value the list item can be removed.

How can I check my list values and change them?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches. In the procedural one, you iterate over the list items and modify or skip the element:

```
let newlist = []
for element in mylist
    " Parse element.
    if ! OutsideBounds(element)
        call add(newlist, AdjustBounds(element))
    endif
endfor
```

In the functional programming approach, you use the built-in `map()` to modify elements (i.e. adjust the bounds), but that one cannot remove elements. So just empty those elements and then do a second pass with `filter()` to remove them. Note that both functions modify the original lists, so use `copy()` if you need to keep the original.

```
call filter(map(mylist, 'AdjustBounds(v:val)'), '! OutsideBounds(v:val)')
```

I hope I don't need to tell you how to write the `AdjustBounds()` and `OutsideBounds()` functions...

Comment: thank you, never heard of OutsideBounds() and AdjustBounds(). Where do I have to put the min-value and max-value?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. Did a search on the web but didn't find anything about OutsideBounds() and AdjustBounds()

Comment: No such functions exist, but if you ask such algorithmic questions, you should very well be capable of _writing the functions yourself_; after all, it's just a little bit of splitting and integer comparison. Metaphorically speaking, Stack Overflow is about teaching you to fish, not providing all the fish for you. Otherwise, you would never stop asking...

Comment: I'm learning a lot asking and even before asking I already searched and tried many many hours. But if you want to be a prof. please don't asnwer. I don't not even know what you mean by OutsideBounds and AdjustBounds but now I've understand that you've chosen the names yourself. :(

Comment: For a good start on Vim scripting, read `:help usr_41.txt`; it explains the basics and has pointers to all built-in functions.